# Watch ng-model in multiple nested ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following piece of code

```
                <div ng-repeat="category in categories">
                <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in category">
                    {{ key + ":"}}
                    <select id={{key}} class="my_select"
                            data-ng-model="key.type"
                            data-ui-select2="{}" multiple>
                        <option ng-repeat="c in value"
                                ng-selected="(filters[key].length>0) && (filters[key].indexOf(c.trim()) !== -1)" >
                            {{c.trim()}}</option>
                    </select>

                </div>
            </div>
```

and this one in controller, which never activates(console log doesn't display anything when I change selection):

```
    $scope.$watch('key.type', function(newValue, oldValue){
    console.log("" +newValue + " " + oldValue);
}, true);
```

How can I watch selects in this scenario?
I found numerous answers regarding Angular, ng_repeat and ng_model, but none of them worked for me. 
Any help is appreciated.

what I'm trying to do:
Given categories as [{category : [ laptop, TV]}, {cpu : [ Core i5, Core i7]}]
to build two selects and retrieve selected data (select2 with multiple items)

Comment: What doesn't work? I mean what do you try to achieve and what happens?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Sorry, watch is not watching anything...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way that I found was to edit the select2.js that implements select2 in angular.

```
    $timeout(function () {
      elm.select2(opts);

      // Set initial value - I'm not sure about this but it seems to need to be there
      elm.select2('data', controller.$modelValue);
      elm.on('change', function(a){
          scope.$emit('select2:change', a);
      });
```

then you can use the followind code to listen in your controller:

```
    $scope.$on('select2:change', function (event, element) {

    if(element.added){
        console.log(element);
        console.log(event);
        $scope.updateCategories(event.targetScope.key, element.added.text.trim());
    }
    if(element.removed){
        console.log("Removed");
        $scope.cleanUpOldStuff(event.targetScope.key, element.removed.text.trim());
    }
});
```

Its not the best way, but it works...

Answer (score 0):

When you use the `ng-repeat` directive, you create a new scope that is only accessible within the block containing `ng-repeat`. This block inherits all the scope properties of its parent block.

What this means is that while within the `ng-repeat` block, you can access the `key` property, outside it you cannot.

Thus, placing a `$watch` on it will not work.

What you need to do in this case is to use the `ng-change` directive which is explicitly meant to respond to changes in the `select` tag.

Place this directive on the select as:

```
<div ng-repeat="category in categories">
    <div ng-repeat="(key, value) in category">
        {{ key + ":"}}
        <select id={{key}} class="my_select"
            data-ng-model="key.type"
            data-ui-select2="{}"
            data-ng-change="changeInSelect(key, value)" multiple>
            <option ng-repeat="c in value"
                ng-selected="(filters[key].length>0) && 
                (filters[key].indexOf(c.trim()) !== -1)" >
                    {{c.trim()}}
            </option>
        </select>
    </div>
</div>
```

and then in your controller, define a function that will handle it:

```
$scope.changeInSelect = function (key, value) {
    //DO something here
};
```

Comment: I implemented this approach before, and changeInSelect won't return me any relevant data such as old selection or new selection. watch with normal select is working really nice for me, but not in this nested setup :(